# Can't find element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of `p` tags on the page with id's like:

```
item_1
item_2
item_3
etc.
```

In jquery function I build string for id and than I want to change some value on it but it seams that jquery can't find element with this id, but it's there on the page:

```
...
var itemId = '#item_' + itemId;
                            if ($(itemId).length > 0) {
                                alert("exist");
                            }
...
```

Id is fine in itemId variable. Am I doing something wrong here maybe my approach is wrong?
Markup

```
<div>
       <a href="#"><p id="item_283">Counter</p></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to catch the element directly through the JS console?

Comment: do your `itemId` contains what you desired?

Comment: I have added markup to question. Yes the value is correct.

Comment: If I write this if ($('#item_+283').length > 0) {alert("exist");} to browser console I get 'undefined' but I copy this I from page :(

Comment: `$('#item_+283')` is not right, this should `$('#item_283')`

Comment: @TheSystemRestart fix your comment ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have some sort of variable scope clash, caused by overuse of the `var` keyword.

See this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/acGmQ/ in which I've declared an outer `itemId`, and then inside a function I've replicated your code.

Inside that function the original `itemId` from the outer scope is no longer available, it's `undefined`, so you end up with `#item_undefined`.

Instead, write:

```
var sel = '#item_' + itemId;
if ($(sel).length > 0) {
    alert("exist");
}
```

Comment: All elements are on the page. It's just divs with p tags and on ajax call I need to get this element.

Comment: @fguillen yeah, I finally spotted the `**var** foo = x + foo` bit which rang alarm bells

Answer (score 1):

```
var itemId = '#item_+' + itemId;
```

note the `_+`

thats not right

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
var item = $('#item_'+itemId); if(item.length > 0)....
```

?

Comment: ironically, this would have worked, but I suspect not for the reason you thought it would.

Answer (score 0):

```
var itemId = '#item_' + itemId; // #item_+ << what +?
if ($(itemId).length > 0) {
   alert("exist");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('#item_'+itemId))
{
alert('exist');
}
```